# Affine curve of degree $d$ and multiplicity $d$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be an affine curve defined by a polynomial $p(x,y)$ of degree $d$. Show that if $(a,b)$ is a point of multiplicity $d$ in $C$ then $p(x,y)$ is a product of linear factors, so $C$ is union of d lines through $(a,b)$.

My attempt:

If $p(x,y)$ is homogeneous then by definition of tangent lines as in "Complex Algebraic Curves " by Kirwan we are done. But what if the curve is not homogeneous? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Up to composing $p$ with a translation we may assume that $(a,b) = (0,0)$. Then take the expansion in homogeneous terms
$$
p(x,y) = p_0(x,y) + p_1(x,y) + \dots + p_d(x,y)
$$
where each $p_j(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree $j$.  By the definition of algebraic multiplicity, $p_0 = p_1 = \dots = p_{d-1}= 0$ hence
$$
p(x,y) = p_d(x,y)
$$
is homogeneous and the conclusion follows as you observed in the post.

Comment: could you please explain the step how the lower degree terms are 0

Comment: @user345777 how do you define the multiplicity?

Comment: the least positive integer such that the partial derivative does not vanish

Comment: Well, each $p_j$ is just the sum of the degree $j$ terms of the taylor expansion, hence the conclusion.